# Full browser width list, but text has max-width

Tags: html, css

I have a full browser width list with a background color (which changes color on hover). However I want the `li` text to be `text-align:left`, have a max-width and the left and right margins to be equal – but the background color to still be full browser width. How do I do this?

I have made a JSfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/x2c9qcpm/1/).

As soon as I put a max-width on the `li`, the background color will obviously shrink to the max-width. Is there a way to just target the text within the list?

```
<div class="case_study_links">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="google.html">Abbey Meadow Flowers<br>Helping to grow a sustainable florists</a></li>
        <li><a href="google.html">Collins Environmental<br>Differentiating ecologists from competitors</a></li>
        <li><a href="google.html">University of Oxford<br>Branding for research project on young migrants</a></li>
        <li><a href="google.html">Small Woods<br>New brand brings credibility to organisation</a></li>
        <li><a href="google.html">Good Energy<br>Rebranding helps double customer numbers</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

.case_study_links li {
     list-style: none;
     font-size:1.8rem;
     text-align:left;
     border-top:1px solid white;
}

.case_study_links a:link { color:white; display:block; padding:4.8rem 0; background-color:rgb(149,199,201);}
.case_study_links a:visited { color:white; display:block; padding:4.8rem 0; background-color:rgb(149,199,201);}
.case_study_links a:hover { color:white; display:block; padding:4.8rem 0; background-color:rgb(134,179,181);}
.case_study_links a:active { color:white; display:block; padding:4.8rem 0; background-color:rgb(134,179,181);}
```

Comment: Wrap your a text in a span and add what you want there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your text in a `<span class="my-text">` and add following CSS properties to it:

```
.my-text
{
    max-width:100px; /* or anything you want */
    margin:auto
}
```

Answer (score 2):

U have your CSS on wrong levels:

- Define background-color on the ul (maybe width: 100%; too, didn't test)
- Define borders and width: 100%; on the li
- Define max-width: ; on the a, or the elements within a

As suggested, you could wrap a part of the text in a span element.
I would refrain from using "br", you could do this:

```
<li><a href="google.html"><p>Abbey Meadow Flowers</p><p>Helping to grow a sustainable florists</p></a></li>
```

Change the P elements accordingly for semantic HTML to H1,H2,H3,span,p, etc.
Note that span is an inline element, and will not automatically take up full width. Use display: block; in your CSS to fix this